# Trying to call viewmodel function in custom binding init

Tags: knockout.js

I am very new to using KO.  I am trying to call one of my functions in my viewmodel in the init section of a custom binding.  I have not found much help after searching.  The issue is when I hit the tab key in the input field I get this error: `TypeError: viewModel.addLine is not a function`.  My other question is, what I am supposed to put after `enterPress`?  Right now I am just putting a random string that does nothing for me.

HTML:

```
<input data-bind="value: retail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterPress: 'addRow'" class="form-control" />
```

KO Viewmodel:

```
var itemsModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);

    self.addLine = function() {
        self.items.push({
            itemNo: "",
            brocCode: "",
            itemDesc: "",
            retail: ""
        });
    };

    self.removeItem = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };

};
```

And the custom binding function:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.enterPress = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        element.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13 || keyCode === 9) {
                console.log("hit enter!");
                console.log(element);
                console.log(valueAccessor);
                console.log(allBindingsAccessor);
                console.log(viewModel);
                viewModel.addLine();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};
```

Both of those pieces of code are outside the `$(document).ready(function () {` function.

**Update**

Forgot this piece you guys are asking about.  Here is the rest of the code that gets called after the HTML is set up:

```
function GetItems() {        
    var itemsJSON = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.brochureItems));
    var viewModel = new itemsModel(itemsJSON);
    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
}
```

Comment: How are you applying bindings?  `viewModel` is going to be whatever binding context KO has for that element.  So if it's in a foreach or something, it'll be different.

Comment: It seems like it works. See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sL1cjgsL/ . May be you forgot to create viewModel via `new`? *Note: viewModel is deprecated.* Use `bindingsContext.$root`. See: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Comment: The answer to your second question: you could leave parameter blank: `data-bind="enterPress,someOtherBinding,value: var"`.

Comment: @TarwirdurTuron: Thank you!  `bindingsContext.$root.addLine()` worked for me!  No idea why `viewModel.addLine()` was not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind any ViewModel's function  and access it via `valueAccessor()`, don't you?

Seems it works fine...

```js
var itemsModel = function(items) {
    var self = this;
    self.items = ko.observableArray(items);
    self.retail = ko.observable("");

    self.addItem = function() {
     if ("" === self.retail()) return;
        self.items.push(self.retail());
        self.retail("");
    };

    self.removeItem = function(item) {
        self.items.remove(item);
    };

};

ko.bindingHandlers.enterPress = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var allBindings = allBindingsAccessor();
        element.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
            var keyCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
            if (keyCode === 13 || keyCode === 9) {
                console.log("hit enter!");
                // viewModel.addItem();
                valueAccessor()();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new itemsModel([ "Item1", "Item2", "Item3" ]))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="value: retail, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', enterPress: addItem" class="form-control" />

<ul data-bind="foreach: items">
    <li>
        <span data-bind="click: $root.removeItem">[x]</span>
        <span data-bind="text: $data"></span>
    </li>
</ul>
```